# Dialogflow Show welcome text without user action

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to show welcome text when user initiates the chat i.e. without any action from user. How to achieve this?

I tried NPM dialog flow or @google-cloud/dialogflow to detect intent to trigger the intent using node.js. It is sending the query and showing the fullfillment text in console but not on updating the UI like when user interact with bot.

Thanks.

Comment: You've tagged this with actions-on-google. Is this a Google Action? Or are you using Dialogflow with a different integration? If Dialogflow with a different integration, which are you integrating with? Updating the question with this information, as well as any code, screenshots of Intents you think should be triggered, or any other information will help us understand what you're doing and what isn't working so we can help you.

Comment: @Prisoner, I am using dialog-fulfillment with inline editor. I want to achieve render the welcome message without user interaction .

Comment: Where are you expecting the welcome message to appear? Facebook? Slack? What is the client you're using?

Comment: Currently I am using the test console but basically it would be google assistant on device. I am new to this dialogflow world, Hope I am answering right thing to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Actions on Google, then your welcome Intent will be called when your Action is first invoked. The user wouldn't say anything besides "talk to *action name*".

Using the Actions on Google test emulator, this is provided as a button.

If you're using the Dialogflow tester on the right side of Dialogflow, you need to enter one of the invocation phrases for the Welcome Intent, but these phrases aren't typically used as part of the Action itself.

Comment: Thanks, Got your point. So when I opened the bot in google assistant in my android then I had to enter "Talk to my test app" and then I got the welcome message. Actually I wanted to show the first message from bot without even entering the "talk to my test app"

Comment: So you want your Action to run when you open the Assistant app?

Comment: yes.. like when the chat starts instead of user typing a message, I want to show message from bot. e.g. I am your travel partner, what would you like to do as the first message when chat window opens

Comment: I'm confused. Why would I, as a user, want a random Action starting when I start the Assistant?